# but am getting python - __init__() missing 1 required positional argument error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am new to coding, so started  learning python and  was learning about super() in classes and objects,tried to create a self made program give below but am getting python - **init**() missing 1 required positional argument error please help me
[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPrSM.png)
[part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu1oy.png)

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of your code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3890632) Include a [mre] in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent class (myBrain) takes two arguments-- "name" and "disease". When you pass

```
super().__init__(disease)
```

In line 31 you're only passing in one.
You need to pass in a "name" argument as well or just remove the condition in the parent class.